# What exactly does strace output?

Tags: strace

**Exact** is what I'm focusing on here...

```
mmap(0x37aa74d000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14d000) = 0x37aa74d000
```

All are saying that strace returns all syscalls used,but I `grep entry.S` and there's only `sys_mmap` not simply `mmap`,which means `mmap` is not syscall,should be `sys_mmap`.

So what **exactly** is strace outputing??

Another question is that I think `= 0x37aa74d000` means the return value,right?But what if the function doesn't have return type?(`void`)?

Answer (score 3):

`strace` produces the names of the system calls from *user space*'s perspective: so `mmap`, `open`, `read`, `write`, etc.  This will be different from the function call that was coded when the libc wrapper does something more complicated than just trap into the OS.  For instance, if you call `sigaction` in your code, `strace` will show you a call to `rt_sigaction`, because for many years now, `rt_sigaction` has been the most general system call for setting signal actions, so GNU libc implements all of the signal-setting functions in terms of that primitive.  (In this case, it happens that you cannot call `rt_sigaction` directly, because glibc doesn't expose a wrapper for it -- I don't know why that is.)

`sys_mmap` is the name of a function inside the Linux kernel that *happens* to be the entry point for the `mmap` system call.  Linus could have chosen any naming convention he wanted for system call entry points -- `mmap`, `mach_mmap`, `ZwMmap`, whatever -- it's an implementation detail, irrelevant to user space.  So `strace` does not show you those names.

The *only* system calls whose return type is `void` are the ones that terminate the process, such as `exit_group`.  (From a programming-language-design perspective, it would be more accurate to say that they don't *have* a return type, because they don't return.)  `strace` prints those like so:

```
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

All other system calls return *something*, because all of them can, at least theoretically, fail, and they have to tell you if they did.  If there's no value for them to return besides a success/failure indication, then they return an `int` which is zero for success or `-1` for failure, and `strace` prints that verbatim.  [Soapbox: This is a long-standing design error in Unix, going back at least as far as the first implementation of NFS.  It should be impossible for resource deallocation primitives -- `close`, `munmap`, etc -- to fail, and their return type should be `void` to indicate that.  I fully intend to fix this as soon as I get a time machine.]

Answer (score 2):

`mmap`(2) is a libc wrapper around the system call `sys_mmap`. Use `ltrace` if you want to analyse library calls.

`mmap`'s return type is `void*`, which is a non-typed pointer, which is what it returns upon successful mapping.

Comment: Why strace outputs syscall wrappers not directly syscalls??

Comment: what if the syscall return type is `void`?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the excellent answers already given here, it is worth stressing that people often confuse system calls (which are requests made directly to the kernel) and library calls (which generally refer to calls to GlibC functions).

Many GlibC calls have the same name as system calls (eg read, write, open etc) and are simply wrappers for the system call they invoke. Others are not quite so simple, for example the exec family of GlibC functions all use the 'execve' system call to execute a program so all of them will show up as a call to execve in strace.

Often when people talk about system calls they really mean library calls and the function they are using will differ in the strace output.

Answer (score 0):

Strace is printing syscalls, and `mmap` is out of them, check [`man mmap`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap):

> map or unmap files or devices into memory

Here is its definition:

> `void *mmap(void *addr, size_t lengthint " prot ", int " flags ,
>              int fd, off_t offset);int munmap(void *addr, size_t length);`

and the last number is the return value:

> On success, `mmap()` returns a pointer to the mapped area. On error, the value `MAP_FAILED` (that is, `(void *) -1`) is returned, and errno is set appropriately. On success, `munmap()` returns 0, on failure -1, and errno is set (probably to `EINVAL`).

For each syscall you can check their `man` pages. To learn more about `strace` output it-self, check `man strace`.